# Running and Debugging PHP in Eclipse Juno 2013 with XDebug

Tags: php, windows, apache, xdebug, eclipse-juno

Is it really that hard? I am just trying to set up and configure my environment for webdevelopment.
I have Apache 2.4 running on Windows for a while and have been using Notepad++ all the time just to avoid Eclipse. But sometimes I really need to debug by setting breakpoints etc. like in Visual Studio.
Here's what I got:

- Windows 7
- Apache 2.4
- Eclipse Juno
- XDebug 2.2.1
- PHP 5.4.13
- Eclipse PDT

Now I have been trying to figure out the entire day how to run a simple script as
    echo "Hello World";
This just seems impossible to work:
http://puu.sh/2kSuM
There isn't a Test/index.php in my htdocs folder in Apache. I know that it's looking for that. But all I want is just debug this script, why is this so hard to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ supports interactive debugging using DBGP. Search google for

```
notepad++ xdebug php
```

However using it in Eclipse is also easy. Simplest way to get started is to install WampServer  http://www.wampserver.com/en/ which has XDEBUG built in and correctly configured for you.

A google search for

```
eclipse pdt xdebug
```

Will get you easy tutorials to get started.

Comment: Well thank you, the Notepad++ PHP debugger will do. I didn't know about that. But I disagree on how easy it is to get this working in Eclipse. Most of the tutorials are outdated or incomplete.

Comment: That's why I suggested starting with WAMPServer. I used that and the link: http://devzone.zend.com/1147/debugging-php-applications-with-xdebug/ which gave me all I needed to know.

Comment: Well, I'm using Netbeans now, and somehow setting up everything in Netbeans IDE worked fluently. I really don't understand why Eclipse is making it so hard to work. I can easily put the files in my Apache's htdocs folder to a project in Netbeans and debug with XDebug without causing any problems.

Comment: As long as you are sorted :-)